# How to get_template_part() based on subdomain url?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, subdomain

So I'm making some white labels for my website, they're on different subdomains on the server.

I'm wondering if I can get a template part based on a subdomain, something like this:

```
if (subdomain = 'something') {
   get_template_part('template-part', 'header_test');
}
```

I've been searching onine for some time now, not much info on this.

Comment: i dont understand, on a different subdomain and different theme? are the different template parts for each subdomain in the same theme? and its being used?

Answer (score 0):

For this example we have two domains:

```
http://www.example.com
http://subdomain.example.com
```

To use different templates for the subdomain, we can accomplished this with these steps:

1) Setup subdomain to point to a different directory on your server:

```
Domain: /home/wherever/public_html
Sub-domain: /home/wherever/public_html_subdomain
```

2) Copy your index.php file over to your new subdomain directory and update the CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH variable to point to the location you want to have your templates. In this example, both template folders are above web root.

```
// index.php for domain
define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../templates").'/');

// index.php for subdomain
define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../templates_subdomain").'/');
```

Your template folders now look like:

```
/home/wherever/public_html
/home/wherever/public_html_subdomain
/home/wherever/templates
/home/wherever/templates_subdomain
```

Answer (score 0):

simple approach:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if($host == "YOURSUBDOMAIN") {
  define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', '../templates/_external');
};
```

so far it works perfectly